# Javascript does not work in WebView below Android 4.4.4

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am trying to load a local js file from the assets folder in a web view.

It works perfectly under Android 4.4.4 and Android 5 but not under Android 4.3 and lower versions.

The css is displayed correctly but the js does not seem to be loaded.

This is my code:

```
private static final String HTML_CHARSET = "<meta charset='utf-8'>";
private static final String HTML_TITLE = "<title>Aufbau einer Tabelle</title>";
private static final String HTML_STYLESHEET = "<link href='matrix.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'/>";
private static final String HTML_SCRIPT1 = "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>";
private static final String HTML_SCRIPT2 = "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>";
private static final String HTML_SCRIPT3 = "<script src='matrix.js' type='text/javascript'></script>";
private static final String HTML_VIEWPORT = "<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>";

private static final String HTML_STRING = "<!doctype html> <html> <head> " + HTML_CHARSET + HTML_TITLE + HTML_STYLESHEET + HTML_SCRIPT1 + HTML_SCRIPT2 + HTML_SCRIPT3 + HTML_VIEWPORT + "</head> <body> <table> %s%s </table> </body> </html>";
```

...

```
    String htmlString = String.format(HTML_STRING, htmlTableHeader, tableBody);

    WebSettings settings = matrixWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    matrixWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

loadDataWithBaseURL doesn't need to be prefixed with "file://" or the path. It needs just the HTML content.

loadURL can be used to load a file contents.